# PHP-Paragraph in Echo statement error?

Tags: php

I want to echo these two strings. This is my current code:

```
echo str_replace(array_keys($swears), array_values($swears), $main).<br />;

echo str_replace(array_keys($swears), array_values($swears), $post).<br />;
```

But it produces this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\new.php
```

Please let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead since you have to use quotes for displaying HTML tags:

```
echo str_replace(array_keys($swears), array_values($swears), $main)."<br />";

echo str_replace(array_keys($swears), array_values($swears), $post)."<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo str_replace(array_keys($swears), array_values($swears), $main) . '<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Ths 
 is a string, so it has to be quoted.

```
echo str_replace(array_keys($swears), array_values($swears), $main). '<br />';
```

Comment: how does this question get asked?